# call my function from API to front using react and node

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api, express, webpack

i need to call my connexion() (api/connexion) from my API to the front(using react), it's an authentication function, it should generate a token and i need to get this one on front (render()) to use it for listing my contacts for example

what i did is getting contacts using a token that i included on code from postman, i don't have to do that, the token should be taken when connexion() is good.

the connexion() verify if i had insert the correct email and password, and generate a token.

```
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            // name: "",
          cnx_mail: '',
          cnx_pwd: '',
          joinByEmail: '',
          items: [],
          token : '',
          redirectToReferrer:false,
          errors: {},

          formErrors: {cnx_mail: '', cnx_pwd: ''},
          emailValid: false,
          passwordValid: false,
          formValid: false
        }
         this.handleUserInput = this.handleUserInput.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
      }
```

```
        event.preventDefault();
        let token = localStorage.getItem('tok');
// const token = user.data.result;
        axios.post(`${API}/api/connexion`)
        .then(res => {
            console.log(token);    
            console.log(res);

        this.setState({
            items: res.data,  /*set response data in items array*/
            // isLoaded : true,
            // redirectToReferrer: false
        })})
        // console.log(this.items)
      }
```

```
                                <form className="demoForm" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} noValidate  encType="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
                                    <div className="alreadysubscribed-input">
                                        <div className={`alreadysubscribed-field group-input ${this.errorClass(this.state.formErrors.cnx_mail)}`}>
                                            <input type="email" required className="form-control fatb-input input-form" name="cnx_mail"
                                                value={this.state.cnx_mail}
                                                id="cnx_mail"
                                                onChange={this.handleUserInput} error={errors.cnx_mail} />
                                                <label className="fatb-label" htmlFor="cnx_mail">Email</label>
                                                <div className="fatb-bar"></div>                                  
                                        </div>

                                        <div className={`alreadysubscribed-field group-input ${this.errorClass(this.state.formErrors.cnx_pwd)}`}>
                                            <input type="password" required className="form-control fatb-input input-form" name="cnx_pwd"
                                                value={this.state.cnx_pwd}
                                                id="cnx_pwd"
                                                onChange={this.handleUserInput} error={errors.cnx_pwd} />
                                                <label className="fatb-label" htmlFor="cnx_pwd">Mot de passe</label>
                                                <div className="fatb-bar"></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <FormErrors formErrors={this.state.formErrors} />

                                    <div className="btn-cnx">
                                        {/* <span className="mas">Se connecter</span> */}
                                        <button className="fatb-btn bubbly-button btn-anim3 w100p" type="submit"  name="cnx_btn" disabled={!this.state.formValid}>se connecter</button>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
```

and here is the connexion() fron the backend :

```
/**
 * POST /api/connexion 
 */
exports.connnexion = (req, res) => {
    try{
        var email = req.body.email;
        var password = req.body.password;
        //get email and password
        if( ( (typeof email !== 'undefined') || (email === '') ) || 
        ( (typeof password !== 'undefined') || ( password === '') ) ){
            //check email if Exist in DB
            Account.find({email : email},function(err, account){
                if (err){
                    resultats = {
                        "success": false,
                        "message": "Error : "+err,
                        "result": ''
                    }
                    res.json(resultats);
                }
                else{
                    if((account[0].google.id)===undefined && (account[0].facebook.id)===undefined){//dont have google & facebook account
                        console.log('connexion classique');
                        if(account.length){
                            //if exist,
                            //get password of this account
                            if(bcrypt.compareSync(password,account[0].password)){//if password ok
                                //create new token
                                try{
                                    jwt.sign({
                                        account
                                    },
                                    'secretKey',
                                    (err,token) => {
                                        if(err){
                                            resultats = {
                                                "success": false,
                                                "message": 'Error : '+ err,
                                                "result": ''
                                            }
                                            res.json(resultats);
                                        }
                                        resultats = {
                                            "success": true,
                                            "message": "SUCCESS",
                                            "result": token
                                        }
                                        res.json(resultats); 
                                    }); 
                                }catch(e){
                                    resultats = {
                                        "success": false,
                                        "message": 'Error : '+ e,
                                        "result": ''
                                    }
                                    res.json(resultats);
                                }
                            }
                            else{
                                resultats = {
                                    "success": false,
                                    "message": "Error, check email/password",
                                    "result": ''
                                }
                                res.json(resultats);
                            }

                        }
                        else{
                            resultats = {
                                "success": false,
                                "message": 'Error : check email/password',
                                "result": ''
                            }
                            res.json(resultats);
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        console.log('impossible de se connecter(google ou facebook)');
                        resultats = {
                            "success": false,
                            "message": "Error, check email/password",
                            "result": ''
                        }
                        res.json(resultats);
                    }

                }
            });
        }
        else{
            resultats = {
                "success": false,
                "message": 'Error : check email/password',
                "result": ''
            }
            res.json(resultats); 
        }
    }catch(e){
        resultats = {
            "success": false,
            "message": 'Error : '+ e,
            "result": ''
        }
        res.json(resultats); 
    }
}
```

with this code, i got my toket (using console.log(token))
and all this data generated with api/connexion:

```
config: {url: "http://localhost:3001/api/connexion", method: "post", headers: {…}, transformRequest: Array(1), transformResponse: Array(1), …}
data: {success: false, message: "Error : check email/password", result: ""}
headers: {content-type: "application/json; charset=utf-8", content-length: "70"}
request: XMLHttpRequest {onreadystatechange: ƒ, readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, …}
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
__proto__: Object
```

but if you see on 'data' it rendering we have :

```
message: "Error : check email/password"
result: ""
success: false
```

instead of result : the_token and message : SUCCESS, success: true

PS: IT WORKs VERY WELL IN POSTMAN:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "message": "SUCCESS",
    "result": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJhY2NvdW50IjpbeyJkYXRlQ3JlYXRpb24iOiIyMDE5LTEwLTA5VDIxOjU0OjE4LjQ5MVoiLCJyZXNldHBhc3N3b3JkdG9rZW4iOm51bGwsInJlc2V0cGFzc3dvcmRleHBpcmVzIjpudWxsLCJyb2xlIjoiYWRtaW4iLCJlbmFibGUiOnRydWUsIl9pZCI6IjVkOWU2NzdlMjY4Mjk3MWMxZmMzNzExZCIsImVtYWlsIjoibWlrYS5hY2hlbWxhbEBnbWFpbC5jb20iLCJwYXNzd29yZCI6IiQyYiQxMCRCZzRuT3JOTXpjLmIvSkJOS05pUlAuQmlNZC8uaDRDSEtpeTBudlYvdWltMGQzVndIbDlpcSIsInRpY2tldHMiOltdLCJnYWlucyI6W10sIl9fdiI6MH1dLCJpYXQiOjE1NzE4NTc0ODV9.cGfWeWxaz2fKs8LIVEGzQvQXmRiE63GDioVN2IMerfg"
}
```

THANK YOU

Comment: `if( ( (typeof email !== 'undefined') && (email !== '') ) &&
        ( (typeof password !== 'undefined') &&( password !== '') ) )` both the password and email must be valid right?  then it must `&&` instead of `||`. use `console.log` inside each `if` and `else` statements so that you will know what location the error

Comment: hey, i need to get my email and password from db to compare them with inputs but i dont know how to do that, in postman for example, i enter the mail and password in body (KEY and VALUE) and it return the token and success message as shown on the desc

Comment: I have added console logs.. check it out and let me know what's the error message. check your node server (not browser console).. https://pastebin.com/JSvpqReS

Comment: hey blueeal, what should i put on console.log ? and i saw that the error is comming from the first 'if' , this one :

```if( ( (typeof email !== 'undefined') || (email === '') ) || 
        ( (typeof password !== 'undefined') || ( password === '') ) ){...
```
i have this : 

  ```
else{
            resultats = {
                "success": false,
                "message": 'Error : check email/password7777',
                "result": ''
            }
            res.json(resultats); 
        }```

Comment: and this in browser soncole :

```data: {success: false, message: "Error : check email/password", result: ""}```

Comment: not browser console.. check nodejs server console.. i.e. terminal output from nodejs... did you use my code?

Comment: hey, I DID IT

```handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        fetch(`${API}/api/connexion`, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',   
              },
            body: JSON.stringify ({
                email: this.state.cnx_mail,
                password: this.state.cnx_pwd,
              })
        })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(json => {
            console.log(json);
            localStorage.setItem('toktok', json.result);
        }); }```

Answer (score 0):

i found this solution :

```
   handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        fetch(`${API}/api/connexion`, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',   
              },
            body: JSON.stringify ({
                email: this.state.cnx_mail,
                password: this.state.cnx_pwd,
              })
        })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(json => {
            console.log(json);
            localStorage.setItem('token', json.result);
        }); 
      }
```

now i have to get the 'token' to use it on all my components